# Using alias to change ls to ls-l changes(or disables) the colors of ls output

Tags: colors, alias, ls

I've used alias to change `ls` to `ls -l`, but the colours change to the normal font of the terminal (also tried `ls -l` before the alias command and the colours appeared fine).

What is wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After searching more, I found about the --color option so I used this:

`alias ls="ls -l --color"` and it worked fine!

Comment: Just a note for mac users, the code would be `alias ls="ls -l -G"` via [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/183892/109639)

Comment: This works for the color, but the slashes that follow folders seem to be gone now.